# CSS: Is there a way to apply inherited padding as negative margin?

Tags: css

**Context**

I'm using React and `<td>` must be clickable with `<Link>` of react-router-dom. Padding of `<td>` changes when I resize browser window because it uses css framework named Carbon. I have to `<Link>` = `<a>` tag to fit width/height of `<td>`. It means that when I click `<td>`, hyperlink has to work as expected.

**Problem**

It can bo solved by negative margin, and it should be same with padding. But, padding is dynamic. Therefore, I want to use inherited padding as negative margin.

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
     <a href="google.com">link</a>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

```css
a {
  padding: inherit;
  margin: <negative of inherited padding>
}
```

I cannot know padding of parent because it is dynamic. Actually, my real code is from https://react.carbondesignsystem.com/?path=/story/datatable--default which is framework I'm using.

How can I solve it?

Comment: can you add your html/css at least example that we can understand u better...

Comment: @לבנימלכה I added code

Comment: Does it have to be solved by using css and html only?

Comment: @retterBadach No, it can be treated through JS, but handling DOM element is not recommended because it is using React.

Comment: @Haram Bae Oh, I already posted a sketch answer. It is not really intrusive since you only apply a style change. Maybe as last resort?

Answer (score 1):

Last resort javascript solution:
1) Add a [resize-event listener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/resize_event) to the window.
2) Use [getComputedStyle](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle) to get the padding on resize.
3) Check console for output and adjust string to your needs.
4) Add the wanted minus sign and set the margin via the [style property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ElementCSSInlineStyle/style).

Answer (score 1):

**Use code as below**

[Here I wrote an example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-qaxbrd?file=index.js)

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import "./style.css";

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      padding: 0
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const el = this.divElement;
    const style = window.getComputedStyle(el);
    const padding = style.getPropertyValue("padding").match(/\d+/);;
    this.setState({ padding });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <a
              ref={divElement => {
                this.divElement = divElement;
              }}
              href="google.com"
              style={{margin: this.state.padding* -1 }}>
              link padding: <b>{this.state.padding}px</b>
            </a>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Comment: Oh, great idea... Thanks for korean lol. I tried and accepted if it could be.

Answer (score 0):

Use CSS variables to define the padding:

```css
.box {
  --p:20px;
  padding:var(--p);
  display:inline-block;
  border:1px solid;
}

.box > a {
  margin:calc(-1*var(--p));
  padding:inherit;
  display:block;
  background:red;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"><a href=""> link</a></div>
<div class="box" style="--p:30px;"><a href=""> link</a></div>
<div class="box" style="--p:10px;"><a href=""> link</a></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but padding can be defined in your code. However, padding can be ONLY DEFINED BY FRAMEWORK. It means that I cannot know the parent padding. It changes dynamically